# Problem with c# regular expression for extracting meta tags

Tags: .net, regex

I have this regular expression that extracts meta tags from HTML documents but it gives me errors while I incorporate it in my web application.

the expression is

```
@"<meta[\\s]+[^>]*?name[\\s]?=[\\s\"\']+(.*?)[\\s\"\']+content[\\s]?=[\\s\"\']+(.*?)[\"\']+.*?>" ;
```

is there anything wrong with it?

Comment: The regex looks valid.  It would help if you posted some sample code that is throwing the error.

Comment: It would be nice if you actually state the error that the regexp is giving you. And maybe a bit larger code sample, with the line the error occurs on.

Comment: The regex will also parse invalid input (e.g. as <meta name="a"""""" content="b""""). I found that it is easier to do this kind of parsing in multiple steps: 1) get meta tags; 2) get name:value pairs. It will be easy to maintain, and more flexible (e.g. will support content and name attributes in reverse order).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You're using both the @ (verbatim string) syntax and escaping your slashes in the sample you posted. You need to either remove the @, or remove the extra slashes and escape your double quotes by doubling them up, then it should work.

(For what it's worth, if you're going to be working with regular expression on an ongoing basis, I would suggest investing in a copy of [RegExBuddy](http://www.regexbuddy.com/).)

Comment: They're called "verbatim strings". And one of the benefits of RegexBuddy is that, after helping you create the right regex, it can export the regex in whatever format you need, including C# verbatim strings.

Answer (score 6):

When using a string literal (@"") you don't need to double the back-slashes -- everything in the string is accepted as it is -- except for double quotes, which need to be doubled:

`@"<meta[\s]+[^>]*?name[\s]?=[\s""']+(.*?)[\s""']+content[\s]?=[\s""']+(.*?)[""']+.*?>"`

Answer (score 0):

Jeromy is right. You're using an escaped string and a string litteral. The regex itself is fine... So I guess that's where the problem is.